# Python compare bombs if files not sorted

Tags: python, csv

I have written some code to compare two files via a search string.

The file = master data file
The checkfile = list of states & regions

When I have more than 1 state in the file that is not in sorted order it bombs out.

How can i get this to work without having to sort my "file"

The Error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gangnamstyle.py", line 27, in 
    csvLineList_2 = csv2[lineCount].split(",")
IndexError: list index out of range

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
file = raw_input("Please enter the file name to search: ") #File name
checkfile = raw_input("Please enter the file with the search data: ") #datafile
save_file = raw_input("Please enter the file name to save: ") #Save Name
search_string = raw_input("Please type string to search for: ") #search string
#row = raw_input("Please enter column text is in: ") #column number - starts at 0
#ID_INDEX = row
#ID_INDEX = int(ID_INDEX)
f = open(file)
f1 = open(save_file, 'a')
csv1 = open(file, "r").readlines()
csv2 = open(checkfile, "r").readlines()


#what looks for the string in the file
copyline=False
for line in f.readlines():
 if search_string  in line:
  copyline=True
  if copyline:
    f1.write(line)

for lineCount in range( len( csv1) ):
    csvLineList_1 = csv1[lineCount].split(",")
    csvLineList_2 = csv2[lineCount].split(",")
    if search_string == csvLineList_2[0]:
    f1.write(csvLineList_2[2])



f1.close() #close saved file
f.close() #close source file
#csv1.close()
#csv2.close()
```

Comment: It "bombs out". What's the error message, and on which line did it occur?

Comment: This is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gangnamstyle.py", line 27, in <module>
    csvLineList_2 = csv2[lineCount].split(",")
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

OK, so that error message is an `IndexError: list index out of range` in the line `csvLineList_2 = csv2[lineCount].split(",")`. There's only one indexing happening there, so apparently `lineCount` is too big for csv2.

lineCount is one of the values of range(len(csv1)). That makes it automatically in range for csv1. Apparently csv1 and csv2 are not the same length, causing the IndexError.

Now that's quite possible, because they contain lines from different files. Apparently the files don't have equal number of lines.

To be honest I have no clue why you are reading the lines into csv1 at all. You loop over those lines and split them (into the variable `csvLineList_1`), but you never use that variable.

I think your loop should just be:

```
for line in csv2:
    parts = line.strip().split(",")  # line.strip() removes whitespace and the newline
                                     # at the end of the line
    if search_string == parts[0]:
        f1.write(parts[2] + "\n")  # Add a newline, you probably want it
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that worked well..  I just need to figure out how to have each line have the item... right now I get: 
DC,22,2,109%,0.64
DC,44,4,218%,12.1
DC,1231,12,12%,12
DC,131,121,11%,11
Region1
 I would prefer to have 
DC,131,121,11%,11 - Region1  
DC,1231,12,12%,12 - Region1   

All on a new line of course - it didnt format right when I posted

Comment: Also what is python's line limit.. One file has 52 and one 54

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is probably due to the file lengths not being equal.

It's not exactly clear from what you've written, what you're hoping to do. It looks to me like (maybe) you want to find a search term in "master file", and if you find it, write the line you find to the "save file". It also looks to me like you want to find that same search term in the very first field of the "check file", and if you find it, write the contents of the third field into the "save file". If that's wrong, it's because your code has bugs.

Either way, there's a bunch of issues in the code you've posted, and you're probably going to get at least some mileage out of using the `csv` module to do what you're trying to do.

Maybe post a fuller problem description.

Edit:

```
import csv
import sys

def build_state_lookup(fn):
    with open(fn) as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        # throw away first line
        reader.next()
        # now build a dictionary mapping state to region
        lookup = {state: region for (state, _, region) in reader}
        return lookup

def process_big_file(in_fn, checkfile, out_fn):
    lookup = build_state_lookup()
    with open(in_fn) as infile:
        with open(out_fn, 'w') as outfile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)


            # output the header row
            writer.writerow(reader.next() + ['Region'])
            for row in reader:
                state = row[0]
                region = lookup.get(state, "No Region Found")
                row.append(region)
                writer.writerow(row)


def main():
    process_big_file(*sys.argv[1:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: RemcoGerlich Helped a lot. with his reply..  The files are 55 and 52 lines each.  This is just a test before I scale up to much larger files.   What I am trying to do is there is State,Item,Person,Variance,Days in the "file"  Checkfile has State, Full_State_Name, Region.  

What I want to do is when they enter a state code into the "search string" (e.g. DC) it brings back all the DC lines with the region name after the line.  So in File You may have DC,12345678,John,4%,5 and in checkfile you have all the states like DC, District of Columbia, Region1

Comment: So I think what you have is two files, and you want to join them on "State" and output everything from one file, and the Region from the other?

Comment: I added a complete solution that probably does what you want. Please ask questions about it. :)